# How to write thread safe method common for multiple instances of spring boot application

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

1. I have a situation wherein for a given request a file is generated
   as part of an endpoint code flow.
2. At present we have placed the file
   generation code within synchronized block, to ensure thread safety.
3. Till now we have deployed only 1 instance of application in Jenkins.
4. Now we are planning to deploy 3 instances of our application in Jenkins.

My problem is how do I ensure thread safety of my file generation code now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear. If you have an implementation already, update your question instead of answering your own question.

Coming back to your question, Jenkins is not a deployment environment but a build tool. If you are spinning the server as part of the build process for test execution purposes, it is highly recommended not to have side effects. Either deploy it remotely or use a docker container to run your application.